# How to sort registry key name value by REG_SZ name value in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a registry key that contains multiple string name/data values (they are type REG_SZ). I would like to list the name / data values and sort them by name value. I'd like to do this in powershell. I can get the values with `Get-ItemProperty` with no problem but I'm not sure how to sort with `Sort-Object`. As you can see below it's not sorted.

```
$item = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources' | Sort-Object


PSPath                      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data S
                          ources
PSParentPath                : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI
PSChildName                 : ODBC Data Sources
PSProvider                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
MSDWDATA_DEFAULT_SYBASE4.00 : DataDirect 4.0 Sybase Wire Protocol
Xtreme Sample Database 2003 : Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
NYT_OPS                     : DataDirect 4.2 Sybase Wire Protocol
NYP_OPS                     : DataDirect 4.2 Sybase Wire Protocol
NYP_MSPA2                   : DataDirect 4.2 Sybase Wire Protocol
NYT_MSPA_A                  : DataDirect 4.2 Sybase Wire Protocol
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$p = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources'
$p.PSObject.Properties | Sort-Object Value| Format-Table Name,Value
```

Answer (score 0):

really ugly:

```
$item = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources' | 
out-string -Stream | sort
```

or by value (more ugly):

```
$item = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources' | 
out-string -Stream | sort { ($_.split(':'))[1] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the top google result when I searched so even though its very old I figured it was worth adding.  If you just want to sort display them sorted by name the below works in one line.

```
get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters" | Sort {$_.PSObject.Properties.Name}
```